# Как сделать такую фигуру в svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

Как сделать верхнюю границу блока вогнутой, а нижнюю - выпуклой?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо эллипсами, либо кривыми Безье.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я думал через прямоугольник. Ок, тогда выходит, что надо выгнуть в обратную сторону верхнюю границу и выпрямить боковые грани элемета. Буду очень благодарен за ссылку на ресурс, где можно узнать, как это дело провернуть.

Comment: https://codepen.io/gillescastel/pen/QvZJaw?editors=1100